# Which point of the mountain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, mathematical-modeling

A mountaineer wishes to make a descent from a mountain, starting at the top of the
mountain at $(0, 0)$. The height of the mountain at position (x, y) is given by
$$h(x, y) = 3000 - \frac{1}{10000}(5x^2+4xy+2y^2)$$ 
In 30 minutes, the mountaineer can arrive at any point that lies on a circle with a radius
1000 and centered at $(0, 0)$. Which point should the mountainer target if he is to descent as much as possible?

Using Lagrange function

Comment: For getting some idea can you roughly hand sketch the circle on this mountain?

Comment: @MariyaKav Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the algebra a bit by realizing that you are really just looking to maximize $$f(x,y) = 5x^2+2xy+2y^2 $$ 
subject to the constraint $$g(x,y)=x^2+y^2=1000$$
so that $$f(x,y) = 3x^2+2xy+2000 $$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We need to find the minimum of $h(x,y)$ with the constraint $x^2+y^2=1000$.

To solve we need to apply Lagrange multipliers for $x^2+y^2=1000$, that is solve the system

- $h_x=2\lambda x$
- $h_y=2\lambda y$
- $x^2+y^2=1000$

Comment: Ah,thank you so much, but how could you understand from the exercise that you need to find miminun on $h(x,y)$?

Comment: @MariyaKav Reading again the OP it seems that we are requested to find the minimum exactly for $x^2+y^2=1$ thus we don't need to solve the first part. I fix that

Comment: @MariyaKav The OP ask "Which point should the mountainer target if he is to descent as much as possible?" that is exactly the minimum of h(x,y) with the given constraint.

Comment: It might be (though I haven't checked) that the climber should target some point *within* the circle. It's worth making sure of.

Comment: @CameronBuie At first I had the same idea but the OP states that "In 30 minutes, the mountaineer can arrive at any point that **lies on a circle with a radius 1000** " thus I think that the interior point are excluded.

Comment: The words seem to exclude it, yes, but it wouldn't really make much sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here we got ,
$$3000-\frac{2 {{y}^{2}}+4 x y+5 {{x}^{2}}}{10000}=\lambda\, \left( {{y}^{2}}+{{x}^{2}}-1000000\right)........(1) $$
$$-\frac{y}{2500}-\frac{x}{1000}=2 \lambda x ........(2)$$
$$-\frac{y}{2500}-\frac{x}{2500}=2 \lambda y ........(3)$$
solving for the minimum value,we get-
$$\lambda=-\frac{3}{5000}$$
$$x=\pm400\sqrt{5}$$
$$y=\pm200\sqrt{5}$$
Hence, $$h=2400 m $$